# Trigger validation of single react hook form input field while passing value to the input

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, zod

I have a complex form on multiple pages built with react-hook-form. In my form provider I am using this setup:

```
  const methods = useForm<formType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formZod),
    mode: "onBlur",
    defaultValues: formDefaults,
  });
```

Now for the last field for email, I would like to trigger validation of this one specific field on the onChange event. The field looks like this inside a React component:

```
      <TypedInput
        type="email"
        name="summary.email"
        placeholder={"Input email here"}
      />
```

The "name" prop refers to the FieldPath for hook react-hook-form and `<TypedInput>` is just a wrapper around a Controller that further passes the data to a classical html `<input>` tag, so I am able to use any HTML input attributes here (and it should mostly act like a regural `<input>`).

I've tried to use `onChange()` handler and trigger validation with function `trigger()` from `useFormContext()` in a helper function but then the value does not get saved to the input field. Something like this example below:

```
const { trigger } = useFormContext<formType>();

const validateEmail = (e) => {
  trigger("summary.email");
}

/* component */
      <TypedInput
        type="email"
        name="summary.email"
        placeholder={"Input email here"}
        onChange((e) => validateEmail(e))
      />
```

Comment: Depending on the implementation of your `TypedInput` component, you may be overriding the `Controller`'s `onChange` handler when you pass your custom `onChange` function to it, possibly because your `TypedInput` implementation consists of spreading the `Controller`'s field handlers like `{...field}`

Comment: could you include the code for TypedInput? this will help pinpoint the solution